# tag synonym annoyance

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Eine neue Frage meinerseits verzierte ich mit dem Schlüsselwort (i.f.: Tag) "Redensart", welches von einem aufmerksamen Geist rasch entsorgt wurde, weil sich eine fehlgeleitete Mehrheit hier auf englische Schlüsselwörter geeinigt hat.

Propagiert haben sie ihre Entscheidung mit der Konvention deutsche Synonyme für Tags anzubieten.

Nun ist es so, dass Tags überhaupt schwer auffindbar sind. Bearbeitet werden dürfen sie auch erst, wenn man Reputation wie Heu hat, was mir glücklicherweise vergönnt ist.

Dennoch darf ich das Tag nicht bearbeiten, sondern muss erst bei Fragen zu diesem Tag 5 Punkte gesammelt haben. Nun - das habe ich mit dieser Frage, die schon eine Aufwertung erhalten hat, aber es klappt dennoch nicht - womöglich zählt das erst nach der nächtlichen Neukalkulation.

Also habe ich nach alten Fragen gesucht, bei denen ich mir meine Reputation erworben habe (hört, hört!) :), und habe, natürlich nur wo es passte, 'idioms' als Schlüsselwort zugefügt. Allein, es half nicht. Wartet wohl auch auf das nächtliche Update.

#### tl;dr

- Ein deutsches Synonym sollte für jedes Schlüsselwort Pflicht sein (Solange Deutsch als Verkehrssprache hier keine Mehrheit hat).
- Wer deutsche Synonyme irgendwo weglöscht sollte, sofern dies nicht inhaltlich, sondern nur der Sprache wegen geschah, prüfen, ob das Wort als Synonym bereits existiert, oder sonst verpflichtet sein, dies umzusetzen, oder für die Umsetzung Verantwortung zu tragen, sonst enden die User wie ich in der Mangelnden-Rechte-Falle.
- Für existierende Tags sollten dt. Synonyme systematisch nachgetragen werden. Es sollte nicht sein, dass man nach "Redensart" sucht, und 0 Treffer findet.

#### Translation to en_US:

I wrote a question with the tag `Redensart`, but soon a helping hand occured, and removed the tag.

After intensive search I found the place, where to create tag synonyms. I found a lot of discussions about language tags too.

They said, that German tags should be synonyms, and English ones default (something I'm not happy about, but that's a different topic). For `idioms`, there was no such synonym. I tried to create one. You need much reputation to do so (1250) and 5 points from questions about that tag.

Summary:

- If you remove a translating tag from a question, create that synonym if it doesn't exist. If you don't have reputation to do so, take responsibility for searching somebody else to create the tag.
- For each tag which has no translation a translation synonym shall be created.
- For every newly created synonym, at least one german translation should be mandatory.